# Store an image in an array using Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to read images (500x300x3) and store them in arrays:

```
import os
import numpy as np

data = np.empty((number_of_images, 3, 300, 500), dtype="float32")

imgs = os.listdir("./images")
num = len(imgs)
for i in range(num):
    img = Image.open("./images/" + imgs[i])
    arr = np.asarray(img, dtype="float32")
    data[i, :, :, :] = arr
```

now here error occurs because the size of `arr` is 500x300x3, but I want to store it as `np.empty((number_of_images, 3, 300, 500), dtype="float32")`.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Transpose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) the array:

```
data[i, :, :, :] = arr.transpose(2, 1, 0)
```